# Pooling of cox regression models going wrong

Tags: r

I have saved the coefficients from a cox regression model (using the survival package) for 54 genetic variants. I have done this for 7 countries separately and now want to pool them together using the `rma` function in the `metafor` package. The cox regression went fine, and I am using the exp(coef) and the robust standard errors for the pooling. This is part of my script

```
library(metafor)   
HR.test <- c(1.0473445, 0.9463692, 0.8108665, 0.9981969, 0.9463692, 0.9858747, 0.9089416)
se.test <- c(0.06669897, 0.05569544, 0.1618536, 0.06813053, 0.05569544,
             0.05663756, 0.08702840)

pool.test <- rma(HR.test, sei=se.test, method="FE")
summary(pool.test)
```

The problem is, that the P values are impossibly small, especially considering that the confidence intervals go through 1, so the results are not significant. Is there something wrong with what I'm typing? 
I've used this package before to pool linear regression results and it worked fine. Is it different if you use hazard ratios (the values are the exponentials of the hazard ratios)?

Comment: If you want CI's you need to first calculate the log-est CI's and then transform. I doubt that exp(se)'s are particularly meaningful. The metafor RMA documentation says you are supposed to be working with the log-relative risk and either se's or variances, so I would think that also means you should NOT use exp(coef) but rather just coef and se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that the code as provided was actually used. First of all, `beta.test` is not defined. I assume that these are supposed to be the *log* hazard ratios extracted from the Cox regression models. Also, `methods="FE"` will give you an error. It should be `method="FE"`.

Indeed, if you run `rma(HR.test, sei=se.test, method="FE")` then you get a very small p-value, but as @42 has already indicated in the comments, this is not correct. The `se.test` values are the estimated standard errors of the *log* hazard ratios. So, `beta.test <- log(HR.test)` and then `rma(beta.test, sei=se.test, method="FE")` is what you should do and this gives a p-value of about .20 for the combined estimate.

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang for your help. That does seem to clear up the problem. I also edited my question to fix the typing mistakes